# Existing Database moved to Azure and used by Azure Mobile Services - Id property Exception

Tags: .net, azure-mobile-services

I had and existing database with 3 tables and relationships between them.  Two of the tables have primary key columns named 'Id' that are integer columns.  The third table has a compound primary key that consists of a foreign key relating to each of the other two tables (a linking table or many to many).

I setup a new Azure Mobile Service and specified this database as the source for the service data.  I built out the controllers, models and data object (DTO's) for the service in .NET.  Everything looks right, but when I try to request data from any of the tables, I get this error:

```
{
message: "The query specified in the URI is not valid. Property 'Id' is of an unrecognized EdmPropertyKind."
exceptionMessage: "Property 'Id' is of an unrecognized EdmPropertyKind."
exceptionType: "Microsoft.Data.OData.ODataException"
stackTrace: " at Microsoft.Data.OData.Query.SyntacticAst.SelectPathSegmentTokenBinder.TryBindAsDeclaredProperty(PathSegmentToken tokenIn, IEdmEntityType entityType, ODataPathSegment& segment) at Microsoft.Data.OData.Query.SyntacticAst.SelectPathSegmentTokenBinder.ConvertNonTypeTokenToSegment(PathSegmentToken tokenIn, IEdmModel model, IEdmEntityType entityType) at Microsoft.Data.OData.Query.SyntacticAst.SelectPropertyVisitor.ProcessTokenAsPath(NonSystemToken tokenIn) at Microsoft.Data.OData.Query.SyntacticAst.SelectPropertyVisitor.Visit(NonSystemToken tokenIn) at Microsoft.Data.OData.Query.SyntacticAst.NonSystemToken.Accept(IPathSegmentTokenVisitor visitor) at Microsoft.Data.OData.Query.SyntacticAst.SelectBinder.Bind(SelectToken tokenIn) at Microsoft.Data.OData.Query.SelectExpandSemanticBinder.Parse(IEdmEntityType elementType, IEdmEntitySet entitySet, ExpandToken expandToken, SelectToken selectToken, ODataUriParserConfiguration configuration) at Microsoft.Data.OData.Query.ODataUriParser.ParseSelectAndExpandImplementation(String select, String expand, IEdmEntityType elementType, IEdmEntitySet entitySet) at System.Web.Http.OData.Query.SelectExpandQueryOption.get_SelectExpandClause() at System.Web.Http.OData.Query.Validators.SelectExpandQueryValidator.Validate(SelectExpandQueryOption selectExpandQueryOption, ODataValidationSettings validationSettings) at System.Web.Http.OData.Query.SelectExpandQueryOption.Validate(ODataValidationSettings validationSettings) at System.Web.Http.OData.Query.Validators.ODataQueryValidator.Validate(ODataQueryOptions options, ODataValidationSettings validationSettings) at System.Web.Http.OData.Query.ODataQueryOptions.Validate(ODataValidationSettings validationSettings) at System.Web.Http.OData.EnableQueryAttribute.ValidateQuery(HttpRequestMessage request, ODataQueryOptions queryOptions) at System.Web.Http.OData.EnableQueryAttribute.ExecuteQuery(Object response, HttpRequestMessage request, HttpActionDescriptor actionDescriptor) at System.Web.Http.OData.EnableQueryAttribute.OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)"
}
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

In order to access a database from Azure Mobile Services each table must conform to the following requirements:

> - The table must be in the schema of your Mobile Service (the schema is the name of your Mobile Service)
> - The table must have an identity column called ‘id’ and it must be all lower case letters

So it sounds like you need to i) ensure that your 2 tables with an `id` primary key are set as identity fields, and ii) add an `id` primary key (which is an identity) to your 3rd table which you can basically ignore in your usage, but will make it acceptable to Azure Mobile Services. You can also create an index for the old primary key for performance purposes.

I would suggest reviewing [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jpsanders/archive/2013/05/24/using-an-existing-azure-sql-table-with-windows-azure-mobile-services.aspx).